# Why isn't Array.prototype used in express.js

Tags: javascript, express

I'm currently reading the code of the ***request.js*** module in ***express.js*** and I was wondering why `[].slice.call()` is invoked instead of the usual `Array.prototype.slice.call()`. Do we gain something by doing this?

```
req.is = function(types) {
  if (!Array.isArray(types)) types = [].slice.call(arguments);
  return typeis(this, types);
};
```

Comment: It's shorter. There is no other difference.

Comment: `[ ]` is the "short cut" to create new array instances which inherit from `Array.prototype`. So basically, it just saves you some typing there. No big deal.